# Django 1.3 to 1.6 Update BaseModelClass

Tags: django

I have a existing app which is build django 1.3, now I am updating it 1.6.

The problem is -

```
staff_formset = modelformset_factory(Staff, formset=EventUserFilteredFormSet, form=EventStaffForm, extra=0)

staff = staff_formset(request.POST or None, queryset=event.staff_set.filter(status=STAFF_STATUS_CHOICES.UNASSIGNED).order_by('service','team'),prefix="staff", user=request.user, event=event)
```

Now EventUserFilteredFormSet class -

```
class EventUserFilteredFormSet(BaseModelFormSet):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.event = kwargs.pop('event',None)
    self.user = kwargs.pop('user',None)
    super(EventUserFilteredFormSet,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    self.management_form.fields['event'] = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput,initial=self.event.pk)

def _construct_forms(self):
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    self.forms = []

    for i in xrange(self.total_form_count()):
        try:
            self.forms.append(self._construct_form(i,instance=self.queryset[i], event=self.event), user=self.user)
        except:
            self.forms.append(self._construct_form(i, instance=None, event=self.event, user=self.user))
@property
def empty_form(self):
    return self._get_empty_form(event=self.event)
```

The problem is _construct_forms is not calling from that class ? Can any one help me out.

Comment: ["this method was removed after 1.5 and I wasn't supporting django 1.6 yet. _construct_form is still there, _construct_forms (with an s) was removed."](https://github.com/RealGeeks/django-modelclone/issues/10)

Comment: @danihp ya now I can see the method is removed - https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.6.x/django/forms/formsets.py.. So what I can do now ?

Comment: overwrite [forms](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.6.x/django/forms/formsets.py#L128)?

Comment: thanks. btw - _get_empty_form I am getting error here. this method is also removed from django 1.6. What is the fixes ?

Comment: Overwrote forms solved issue?

Comment: yes it was, but facing another problem.